# How to reshape dataframe with string variables?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataframe with text data. It looks like this:

```
    var  texts users
1    1  text1 user1
2    2  text2 user1
3    3  text3 user1
4    4  text4 user1
5    5  text5 user1
6    1  text6 user2
7    2  text7 user2
8    3  text8 user2
9    4  text9 user2
10   5 text10 user2
```

Now I want to reorganize this dataframe and use the values of 'var' as column names and change the dataframe into a dataframe with two rows (user1 and user2). Text1 to text10 are the variable values.
I tried reshape2, but I haven't succeeded in doing it properly.

```
library(reshape2)
datafile.melt <- melt(data = datafile, id.vars=c('users','var'), measure.vars=c('texts'))
datafile.values <- dcast(datafile.melt, var ~ users)
```

the result is:

```
  var user1  user2
1   1 text1  text6
2   2 text2  text7
3   3 text3  text8
4   4 text4  text9
5   5 text5 text10
```

As you can see 'user1' and 'user2' changed into column names, and the var values didn't. And I want to change it into:

```
 users     1     2     3     4      5
1 user1 text1 text2 text3 text4  text5
2 user2 text6 text7 text8 text9 text10
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this properly?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `users ~ var` instead of `var ~ users`?

Comment: and that's it! I thought I tried that, but there was an error in my code. If you add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, the answer is simply to use `users ~ var` instead of `var ~ users`:

```
> dcast(datafile.melt, users ~ var)
  users     1     2     3     4      5
1 user1 text1 text2 text3 text4  text5
2 user2 text6 text7 text8 text9 text10
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `reshape` from base R

```
nn<-reshape(df1,timevar="var",idvar="users",direction="wide")
    names(nn)[-1]<-as.character(unique(df1$var))
> nn
  users     1     2     3     4      5
1 user1 text1 text2 text3 text4  text5
6 user2 text6 text7 text8 text9 text10
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I would not rename the resulting names (despite the OP's desired output) for at least 2 reasons: (1) they are now no longer syntactically valid; (2) the attributes created by the `reshape` function to allow convenient reshaping back to the long format have now been lost. Try `reshape(nn)` (with no other arguments) before and after changing the names to see what I mean. Maybe that's not a deal breaker, but still...

Comment: @AnandaMahto : I get what you are saying. Thanks for the comment.